# arraylist que deberia tener 10 elementos solo contiene 2

Tags: java, android-studio

hola tengo este pequeño programa que he hecho para probar, y el problema es que debería meter 10 elementos con el texto "hola" en un `ArrayList` (los añado en un bucle `for`), y tan solo me muestra 2, cuando hago el `Log.i`. Este es el código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList <String> al= new ArrayList();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
        {
            al.add("hola");
            Log.i("hola",al.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu ArrayList debe contener 10 elementos al terminar el bucle:

[image: jorgesys arratlist]

La razón por la cual únicamente imprime dos se debe a Android Studio, me parece que en las últimas versiones de Android Studio se tiene un caché "limitado" y evita realizar impresiones de información repetida, pero la información se tiene guardada dentro del ArrayList, por ejemplo puedes imprimir la cantidad de elementos al terminar el bucle y obtendrás los 10 que se guardan:

```
 Log.i("hola","Elementos: " + al.size());
```

Si deseas que se muestren en el LogCat los elementos, puede agregar un valor que diferencie la información que guardas en el `ArrayList`, por ejemplo:

```
ArrayList <String> al= new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
{
    al.add("hola " + i);
    Log.i("hola", al.get(i));
}
```

de esta forma si se imprimiría la información :

```
hola 0
hola 1
hola 2
hola 3
hola 4
hola 5
hola 6
hola 7
hola 8
hola 9
```

Comment: muy bien, muchas gracias.